# Node - Is there an HTML templating library that performs typechecks?

Tags: html, typescript, templates, ejs, server-side-rendering

I have a nodeJS server that uses exclusively TypeScript.

I need to build a plain HTML page and return it as response body. No interactivity, no javascript, just a plain HTML page with some styling. Looking for a popular library, I went for EJS, but it doesn't seem to have any typecheck in the template.

**Is there a templating library for generating plain HTML, like EJS, but that additionally performs type checks like the templates in Angular and React?**

For instance, in the following template

```
<% if (user) { %>
  <h2><%= user.name %></h2>
<% } %>
```

I would like the typescript compiler to fail if the object "user" does not have a property called "name".